# RxJava2 How to use concat() with more than 4 observables

Tags: rx-java, observable, rx-java2

I currently have this method which works just fine:

```
  public static Observable<MyCustomObject> run(Service networkService) {
    return Observable.concat(
        networkService.getThingOne().map(response -> {
          Request request = response.raw().request();
          MyCustomObject case = new MyCustomObject(request);
          return case;
        }),
        networkService.getThingOne().map(response -> {
          Request request = response.raw().request();
          MyCustomObject case = new MyCustomObject(request);
          return case;
        }),
        networkService.getThingOne().map(response -> {
          Request request = response.raw().request();
          MyCustomObject case = new MyCustomObject(request);
          return case;
        }),
        networkService.getThingOne().map(response -> {
          Request request = response.raw().request();
          MyCustomObject case = new MyCustomObject(request);
          return case;
        })
    );
  }
```

It's just the same observable over and over again. If I add another one in there like so:

```
  public static Observable<MyCustomObject> run(Service networkService) {
    return Observable.concat(
        networkService.getThingOne().map(response -> {
          Request request = response.raw().request();
          MyCustomObject case = new MyCustomObject(request);
          return case;
        }),
        networkService.getThingOne().map(response -> {
          Request request = response.raw().request();
          MyCustomObject case = new MyCustomObject(request);
          return case;
        }),
        networkService.getThingOne().map(response -> {
          Request request = response.raw().request();
          MyCustomObject case = new MyCustomObject(request);
          return case;
        }),
        networkService.getThingOne().map(response -> {
          Request request = response.raw().request();
          MyCustomObject case = new MyCustomObject(request);
          return case;
        }),
        networkService.getThingOne().map(response -> {
          Request request = response.raw().request();
          MyCustomObject case = new MyCustomObject(request);
          return case;
        })
    );
  }
```

then I get a red line under `concat()` and under `return case` but just on the `case` portion.

Anyone have any ideas on this?

**EDIT**: I updated my question title from "Why doesn't this work" to "How can I get this to work"? I essentially have 10 observables that I'd like to stick in concat(), and I will probably add more. So I need something that doesn't have a limit.

Comment: `concat` only allows 4 sources.

Comment: @GVillani82 any idea what I can do in my situation. I have about 10 observables I want to string together. `getThingOne()` ... `getThingTen()`.

Comment: Use `concatArray`.

Answer (score 4):

`concat()` accepts and `Iterable<T>` with the observables that should be concated:

```java
public static Observable<MyCustomObject> run(Service networkService) {
    ArrayList<Observable<MyCustomObject>> observables = new ArrayList<Observable<MyCustomObject>>();

    observables.add(networkService.getThingOne().map(response -> {
            Request request = response.raw().request();
            MyCustomObject case = new MyCustomObject(request);
            return case;
        }));
    observables.add(networkService.getThingOne().map(response -> {
            Request request = response.raw().request();
            MyCustomObject case = new MyCustomObject(request);
            return case;
        }));
    observables.add(networkService.getThingOne().map(response -> {
            Request request = response.raw().request();
            MyCustomObject case = new MyCustomObject(request);
            return case;
        }));
    observables.add(networkService.getThingOne().map(response -> {
            Request request = response.raw().request();
            MyCustomObject case = new MyCustomObject(request);
            return case;
        });
    observables.add(networkService.getThingOne().map(response -> {
            Request request = response.raw().request();
            MyCustomObject case = new MyCustomObject(request);
            return case;
        }));

    return Observable.concat(observables);
}
```

*Pardon any syntactical errors, I haven't done Java in a while*